Why don't Steam-Methane Reformers have pilot burners?
Reformers like other fired furnaces burn fossil fuels usually naphtha or natural gas to provide the heat required for the reaction (steam-methane reforming, in this case). However, unlike other fired furnaces, reformers do not have pilot burners in addition to the main burners. Why is it so?

are you saying that there is not a single reformer in existence that has a pilot burner?

I don’t know about all the reformers in existence, but none of the reformers that I or my colleagues have come across have pilot burners.
